# Give an example of an unbounded sequence {$x_n$} for which {$y_n$} converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $y_n = \max \{x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n\}$ for each positive integer $n$.

Give an example of an unbounded sequence {$x_n$} for which {$y_n$} converges.

I understand this conceptually but having a difficult time finding such a sequence. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: What if the $x_n$'s are negative?

Comment: hmmm i don't think i understand

Comment: What if $x_n=-n$?

Answer (score 3):

If $x_n=-n$, then $y_n=-1$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and hence $\{y_n\}$ converges.